# Irrationality of square root of 2

Tags: geometry

It is possible to explain me the 18th proof of the irrationality of square root of 2 from the following site? 
 http://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/sq_root.shtml

Comment: The proof looks perfectly clear to me, except for a typo; CG=CD should be CG=GD (which is correctly stated earlier).  What needs explanation?  (This doesn't seem appropriate for MathOverflow.)

Comment: Closed, please check the FAQ.

Comment: Christian: on a side note, you may like the analogous elementary proof of the irrationality of the other classic number, the golden ratio. Since it verifies the relation x=1+1/x and 1<x<2, if x were rational, x=p/q with 0<q<p, then also x=q/(p-q), and 0<p-q<q so there is no minimal denominator, a contradiction.

Comment: -1 for not saying *what* the questioner doesn't understand...

Comment: In the future, you'd have better luck directing such questions to sites like http://artofproblemsolving.com.